# Styling the meter element

Tags: html, css

I'm using the meter element to display a star rating from 0 - 5. I got it to work great on Chrome, sort of okay in Firefox, but can't quite get it to work properly in Safari.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/sammiepls/pen/vaPZoL)

For Safari, to properly display the styled meter, I have to add

```
 meter {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

And then everything works. However, once doing that, it ceases to work in Chrome because Chrome will just render the content within the meter and cease to show it completely. Has anyone gotten around this?

P.S. Also, does anyone know why I can't set it like this:

```
&::-webkit-meter-bar,
&::-webkit-meter-optimum-value,
&::-moz-meter-bar {
    //code here
  }
```

And instead have to break it up?

```
&::-webkit-meter-bar,
&::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
   //code here
}

&::-moz-meter-bar {
   // code here
}
```

Much appreciated if anyone has any insight :)

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @AravindS the latest version,  68.0.3440.106 !

Comment: I am also having the same version of chrome and it looks working on my end.

Comment: Hey, in the codepen it works for chrome but not safari. But for it to work in safari, I need to add the  -webkit-appearance: none; to meter, which it then ceases to work in chrome but works for safari. You can test it out in my pen by uncommenting the appearances under meter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone with a hacky way to target only Safari. This allows my styled meter to work across Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Have not managed to figure out why I need to separate the `-webkit` and `-moz` styles. Perhaps in the future when all the browsers implement the element in the same way things will be better.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    meter:not(:root:root) {
         appearance: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not test on Safari

But I would try the following (It works in Chrome, at least)

```
meter {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: meter;
}
```

Chrome has a built-in style of **meter**.

That's why when you set **none** it stops to work. Hopefully, Safari will understand **none**, won't understand **meter** and will keep the first style.

Comment: Ahh I tried your solution but unfortunately Safari does understand meter and changes it to it :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```css
 -webkit-appearance: meter;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
```

Comment: Consider giving more info on why this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `border-color: transparent` for the meter element it works in Safari, don’t ask me why.

Here is a working Codepen for your example:

https://codepen.io/receter/pen/KKQmBLP

Edit: `border: 0;` works as well and is probably better.